# Extracting the integers enclosed in square brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, list

I am trying to extract the integers out of a string using regular expressions in Python. So, there can be whitespace between the number and the brackets, but no other character besides those that make up the integer. My code looks like:

---

```
import re
s = "  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"
print(re.findall(r"\s+\[\w+\]\s\[(\d+)\s\]\s\[\w+\]\s+\[\s(-\d+)\s\]\w+\s\[\+(\d+)\]\w+",s))
```

---

The above code prints:

---

```
[('12', '-43', '12')]
```

---

However, I want the output not to be in the form of tuple, or triple in the above case, but in the list like:

---

```
[12, -43, 12]
```

Comment: did you try to look into how to turn a string into a number in python?

Comment: So your question is "how do I convert a list of a single tuple to a list", or "how do I flatten a nested list/tuple"?

Comment: I got answered, However, your second question looks more logical here according to the situation. I should have asked "how do I flatten a nested list/tuple"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following:

```
import re
s = "  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"
rv = re.findall(r"\s+\[\w+\]\s\[(\d+)\s\]\s\[\w+\]\s+\[\s(-\d+)\s\]\w+\s\[\+(\d+)\]\w+",s)
lst = [int(x) for t in rv for x in t]
```

This will loop over all tuples in `rv` and add each integer to a new list, `lst`. The output in this case is:

```
>>> lst
[12, -43, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to match the values might be shortening the pattern and use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
\[\s*\+?(-?\d+)\s*\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ngZTXu/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ACiFg4)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\[\s*\+?(-?\d+)\s*\]"
test_str = "afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['12', '-43', '12']
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked and helped me get on the right direction, However, it fails of some of the quite similar situations:

test_str = "afd [128+] [47 ] [a34]  [ +-43 ]tt [+12]xxx!"
In this string, your proposed regex will print -43 too, But the rule is, there can be whitespace between the number and the brackets, but no other character besides those that make up the integer. Here, after "[" there is "+" between "["and "-43".